# PATCH endpoint 404 on Upgrade to Springboot Version 3

Tags: spring-boot, rest, kotlin, jwt

I'm in the process of migrating my Kotlin API to Springboot version 3.
I'm having a problem where certain endpoints aren't getting hit, for example::

a `GET` to `localhost:8081/search/hello`
works just fine, here is the `GET` endpoint::

```
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_MYROLE')")
  @GetMapping("/search/{somephrase}")
  suspend fun getSomething(@PathVariable("somephrase") phrase: String): someResponse {
    return myService.getPhrase(phrase)
  }
```

a `PATCH` to `localhost:8081/update/resourceId`
does not, and here is my patch endpoint::

```
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_MYROLE')")
  @PatchMapping("/update/{resourceId}")
  suspend fun updateSomething(
    @PathVariable("resourceId") resourceId: Long,
    @RequestBody updateJson: JsonNode
  ): UpdateResponse {
    return recommendationService.update(updateJson, resourceId)
  }
```

Here is the reponse I get::

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-02-12 09:59:50",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/search"
}
```

and this in the console::

```
: [preHandle] PATCH /error - operationId: 00000000000000000000000000000000 |
```

Here is my Spring Security Config::

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class ResourceServerConfiguration {
  @Bean
  fun configure(http: HttpSecurity): DefaultSecurityFilterChain? {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests()
      .requestMatchers("/csrf").permitAll()
      .requestMatchers("/**").authenticated()
      .and()
      .csrf()
      .disable()
      .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter { AuthAwareTokenConverter().convert(it) }
    return http.build()
  }
}
```

and here is my token converter (it just adds a couple of extra claims to the token)

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter

class AuthAwareTokenConverter : Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {
  private val jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter: Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> =
    JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter()


  override fun convert(jwt: Jwt): AbstractAuthenticationToken {
    val claims = jwt.claims
    val principal = findPrincipal(claims)
    val authorities = extractAuthorities(jwt)
    return AuthAwareAuthenticationToken(jwt, principal, authorities)
  }

  private fun findPrincipal(claims: Map<String, Any?>): String {
    return if (claims.containsKey(CLAIM_USERNAME)) {
      claims[CLAIM_USERNAME] as String
    } else if (claims.containsKey(CLAIM_USER_ID)) {
      claims[CLAIM_USER_ID] as String
    } else {
      claims[CLAIM_CLIENT_ID] as String
    }
  }

  private fun extractAuthorities(jwt: Jwt): Collection<GrantedAuthority> {
    val authorities = mutableListOf<GrantedAuthority>().apply { addAll(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.convert(jwt)!!) }
    if (jwt.claims.containsKey(CLAIM_AUTHORITY)) {
      @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
      val claimAuthorities = (jwt.claims[CLAIM_AUTHORITY] as Collection<String>).toList()
      authorities.addAll(claimAuthorities.map(::SimpleGrantedAuthority))
    }
    return authorities.toSet()
  }

  companion object {
    const val CLAIM_USERNAME = "user_name"
    const val CLAIM_USER_ID = "user_id"
    const val CLAIM_CLIENT_ID = "client_id"
    const val CLAIM_AUTHORITY = "authorities"
  }
}

class AuthAwareAuthenticationToken(
  jwt: Jwt,
  private val aPrincipal: String,
  authorities: Collection<GrantedAuthority>
) : JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities) {
  override fun getPrincipal(): String {
    return aPrincipal
  }
}
```

What I've tried::

Simplifying the `PATCH` endpoint to simply return a `"hello"` String to rule out an issue with the service.
The result is the same, so I think the point of failure must be my Spring Security configuration.

Any help/pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting! I appear to have found the solution.
I added an extra forward slash to the end of the path in my mapping.
So I changed this::

```
@PatchMapping("/update/{resourceId}")
```

to this::

```
@PatchMapping("/update/{resourceId}/")
```

and it works!

Oddly SpringBoot version 2.X worked just fine with or without the forward slash. But SpringBoot version 3.X requires it.